# Bulk enable product variations in WooCommerce via SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

In WooCommerce, my product variations are disabled so the item appear out of stock despite they are in stock.

I need some help to enable this option in all of my woocommerce product variations.

I want to enable the checkbox where it appears the text "enable" can we enable that box for all the products via SQL code:

[image: i want to enable the checkbox where it appears the text "enable" can we enable that box for all the products via SQL code]

For clarifications see this screenshot:

[image: click this image here for more clarifying]

Comment: Please any feed back on the answer below will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this very simple SQL query on phpMyAdmin that will enable all disabled variations (always do a database backup before - Also check that your table start with `wp_`):

```
UPDATE wp_posts as p
SET p.post_status = 'publish'
WHERE p.post_status = 'private'
AND p.post_type = 'product_variation';
```

Or you can use this custom function that you will run once by browsing any page of your web site (always do a database backup before):

```
function enable_all_disabled_variations(){
    global $wpdb;
    
    return $wpdb->query("
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        SET p.post_status = 'publish'
        WHERE p.post_status = 'private'
        AND p.post_type = 'product_variation'
    ");
}
// Run the function
enable_all_disabled_variations();
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. Once done remove this code.